# Difficulty executing bookmarklet javascript

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm trying to create a bookmarklet app that parses information from Amazon, Etsy, and JCrew and transmits it to a wishlist application built in Rails. I've succeeded in creating a bookmark button that loads my javascript file into the DOM, but it does not seem to be executing correctly and passing the data to my app. Or maybe my javascript is faulty. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I've included my js file below:

```
function() {

function get_amazon_product_info() 
    {
        var title_span = document.getElementById("btAsinTitle");
        var title = title_span.innerText;

        var image_tag = document.getElementById("main-image");
        var image = image_tag.getAttribute("src");

        var price_span = document.getElementById("actualPriceValue");
        var price = price_span.innerText;

        var product_info = {
            title: title,
            image: image,
            price: price
        }
        return product_info
    }

function get_etsy_product_info()
{
        var title_span = document.getElementById("item-title");
        var title = title_span.innerText;

        var image_div = document.getElementById("fullimage_link1");
        var image_tag = image_div.getElementsByTagName("img");
        var image = image_tag[0].getAttribute("src");

        var price_div = document.getElementsByClassName("item-price");
        var price_span = price_div[0].getElementsByClassName("currency-value")
        var price = price_span[0].innerText;

        var product_info = {
            title: title,
            image: image,
            price: price
        }
        return product_info
}

function get_jcrew_product_info()
{
    var title_span = document.getElementById("pdp-title");
        var title = title_span.innerText;

        var image_div = document.getElementsByClassName("prod_main_img");
        var image_tag = image_div[0].getElementsByTagName("img");
        var image = image_tag[0].getAttribute("src");

        //lame implementation -- need to be able to determine which radio button is checked. Finish later!

        var price_div = document.getElementsByClassName("pdp-shapes");
        var price_span = price_div[0].getElementsByClassName("price")
        var price = price_span[0].innerText;

        var product_info = {
            title: title,
            image: image,
            price: price
        }
        return product_info
}

function determine_params() 
{
        domain = document.domain;
        if (domain == 'www.amazon.com')
        {   
            get_amazon_product_info();
        }
        else if (domain == 'www.etsy.com')
        {
            get_etsy_product_info();
        }
        else if (domain == 'www.jcrew.com')
        {
            get_jcrew_product_info();
        }
}   

function send_data(product_info)
{           
    var link_url = document.URL;
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://max-miller.local:3000/add_product";
    var params = "title=" + product_info[title] + "&image=" + product_info[image] + "&price=" + product_info[price] + "&link_url=" + link_url;
    http.open("POST", url , true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }

    http.send(params);
}

determine_params();
send_data(product_info);
```

}

Comment: +1 for http.onreadystatechange; i will also try it; it never ocured to me this

Comment: Is this the whole file? ... I don't see why it *would* execute. If this is it, you've got a closure that's never executed.

Comment: Also, if this bookmarklet is intended to be executed on domains other than `max-miller.local:3000`, I think you'll need an alternative to `XMLHttpRequest`, since the script will be executing in the context of the *page's* domain.

Comment: i also never used this xmalrequest; i like he simple way; works every time my solution

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps:

I have never sent data like you did, with `http.sed(data)`

However, I created a script element in the head section whenever I needed something from the server;

always use `json.stringify`, this might be one of the reasons that your app fails to send data

and also `if (s.length >= 2000)` be careful here when using my solution, because you can't send/receive infinite data thru 1 request

like this:

```
    function createElementScript(src)
    {

        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = src;
        //console.log("SRC: "+src);
        var header = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
        header[0].appendChild(script);
    }
```

where `src` is created like:

```
var s = JSON.stringify({'url': location.href,
                                    'title': document.getElementById('linkbook_article_title').value,
                                    'description': document.getElementById('linkbook_article_textarea').value
                                });
                                if (s.length >= 2000) {
                                    alert('Payload length is over 2000, action may fail.');
                                }
                                createElementScript(apiURL + "/FollowProduct?input=" + encodeURIComponent(s));
```

my entire bookmarklet, maybe it helps you to improve yours; i used a singleton pattern, just to make sure that i don't reinsert the bookmarklet if a user clicks multiple times on the bookmarklet and i also wanted to encapsulate all the data

```
<?php if (false) { ?><script><?php } ?>
    var LinkbookClass = LinkbookClass ? LinkbookClass : function() {

        var assetsURL = '<?= $this->getAssetsUrl(); ?>';
        var apiURL = '<?= Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl($this->module->id . '/' . $this->id . '/'); ?>';
        var imgsList = new Array();
        var ImgsListImgID = 0;
        //all the images found on the webpage
        var images = 0;
        var imgsListHeightWidth = [];
        var isHighlighting = false;
        var versionStatus;
        var flag1 = false;
        var flag2 = false;
        var precedentObj = null;
        var overlay,
                current,
                handler;
        var extractHL;
        var name = false, price = false, image = false;
        //do we save logs ?
        var consoleLog = true;
        var version_popup;
        var f = function()
        {
            createElementScript(assetsURL + '/sizzle.js?x=<?= $this->module->params['interface_version']; ?>');
            createElementScript(assetsURL + '/xpath.js?x=<?= rand(1, 10000000); ?>');
            //LinkbookPluginCollection.run();

            var popupdividreset = "linkbookreset";
            var DOCreset = document.getElementById(popupdividreset);
            if (DOCreset != null) {
                return false;
            }

            var popupdivid = "linkbookdetails";
            var DOC = document.getElementById(popupdivid);
            if (DOC != null) {
                return false;
            }

            //load css file, force a reload/recache
            addCSS(assetsURL + '/linkbook.css?x=<?= rand(1, 10000000); ?>');
            var divreset = document.createElement("div");
            divreset.id = popupdividreset;
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.id = popupdivid;
            //this will highlight the DOM element that you are hovering
            var divhighlight = document.createElement("div");
            divhighlight.id = "overlayhighlightlinkbook";
            var divOutside = document.createElement("div");
            divOutside.id = "LinkbookOverlay";
            var divLinkbook = document.createElement("divCloseAffair");
            divLinkbook.id = "divLinkbook";
            var str = '<div id="divemptylinkbook"></div>';
            str += divForm('none', div.id, images);
            str += divLogin('none', div.id);
            str += divDetails('none', div.id);
            str += divSuccess('none', div.id);
            str += divBroken('none', div.id);
            div.innerHTML = str;
            divreset.appendChild(div);
            //not used anymore
            //document.body.insertBefore(divreset, document.body.firstChild);

            divOutside.innerHTML = "";
            //inserting the DOM div blank element imediatly after body tag
            divhighlight.innerHTML = "";
            divLinkbook.appendChild(divhighlight);
            divLinkbook.appendChild(divOutside);
            divLinkbook.appendChild(divreset);
            document.body.insertBefore(divLinkbook, document.body.firstChild);
        };
        function addCSS(url) {
            var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            var cssNode = document.createElement('link');
            cssNode.type = 'text/css';
            cssNode.rel = 'stylesheet';
            cssNode.href = url;
            cssNode.media = 'screen';
            headID.appendChild(cssNode);
        }
        ;
        function divLogin(displayTarget, div_id)
        {

            return '<?php $this->renderHTMLtoJS('login', array('js' => array('displayTarget', 'div_id', 'assetsURL'))); ?>';
        }
        ;
        function divForm(displayTarget, div_id, images)
        {

            return '<?php $this->renderHTMLtoJS('form', array('js' => array('displayTarget', 'div_id', 'images', 'assetsURL'), 'url' => $url, 'follower' => $follower)); ?>';
        }
        ;
        function divBroken(displayTarget, div_id)
        {

            return '<?php $this->renderHTMLtoJS('report_broken_url', array('js' => array('displayTarget', 'div_id', 'assetsURL'))); ?>';
        }
        ;
        function divSuccess(displayTarget, div_id)
        {

            return '<?php $this->renderHTMLtoJS('success', array('js' => array('displayTarget', 'div_id', 'assetsURL'))); ?>';
        }
        ;
        function divDetails(displayTarget, div_id)
        {
            return '<?php $this->renderHTMLtoJS('details', array('js' => array('displayTarget', 'div_id', 'assetsURL'), 'url' => $url, 'follower' => $follower)); ?>';
        }
        ;
        function createElementScript(src)
        {

            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = src;
            //console.log("SRC: "+src);
            var header = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
            header[0].appendChild(script);
        }
        ;
        function hideAllDivs() {
            var a = ['LinkbookParrentLogin', 'LinkbookParrentDetails', 'LinkbookParrentForm'];
            for (x in a) {
                var d = document.getElementById(a[x]);
                if (d) {
                    d.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }
        ;
        function divGallery(displayTarget, div_id)
        {
            return '<?php $this->renderHTMLtoJS('gallery', array('js' => array('displayTarget', 'div_id', 'assetsURL'))); ?>';
        }
        ;
        f.prototype = {
            labelEdit: function()
            {
                if (document.getElementById('form_selected_product_name_Linkbook_input').style.display == 'none')
                {
                    document.getElementById('form_selected_product_name_Linkbook_input').style.display = document.getElementById("divemptylinkbook").style.display;
                    document.getElementById('form_selected_product_name_Linkbook_span').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('Linkbook_labelEdit').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('form_selected_product_name_Linkbook_input').value = document.getElementById('form_selected_product_name_Linkbook_span').innerHTML;
                    document.getElementById('form_selected_product_name_Linkbook_input').focus();
                }
            },
            get_article_title: function()
            {
                if (document.title)
                    document.getElementById('linkbook_article_title').value = document.title;
                else
                    document.getElementById('linkbook_article_title').value = location.href;
            },
            get_article_description: function()
            {
                if (document.getElementsByName('description')[0])
                {
                    if (document.getElementsByName('description')[0].getAttribute('content'))
                        document.getElementById('linkbook_article_textarea').value = document.getElementsByName('description')[0].getAttribute('content');
                    else
                        document.getElementById('linkbook_article_textarea').value = 'null';
                }
                else
                    document.getElementById('linkbook_article_textarea').value = 'null';
            },
            init_after_login: function(is_product)
            {
                this.showDiv('LinkbookParrentForm');
            },
            init: function() {
                //console.log('init');
                this.get_article_title();
                this.get_article_description();
                if (<?php
    if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        echo 'true';
    else
        echo 'false';
?>) {
                    this.showDiv('LinkbookParrentLogin');
                } else {

                    Linkbook.init_after_login(<?php
    if (empty($product))
        echo 'false';
    else
        echo 'true';
?>);
                }
            },
            showDiv: function(divId) {
                var d = document.getElementById(divId);
                if (d) {
                    hideAllDivs();
                    d.style.display = document.getElementById("divemptylinkbook").style.display;
                }
            },
            actionSubmit: function(formID, e)
            {
                //alert(formID+'click');
                if (formID == 1)
                    Linkbook.outBound("login");
                if (formID == 2)
                    Linkbook.outBound("follow");
                e.preventDefault();
            },
            toggleItem: function(id) {
                var item = document.getElementById(id);
                if (item) {
                    var parent = item.parentNode;
                    parent.removeChild(item);
                }
            },
            hideDivs: function() {
                hideAllDivs();
            },
            //all the data that has been send from the server to the bookmarlet passed thru this method
            //inBound has 2 parameters, because we need to know the action and the result value
            inBound: function(action, data)
            {

                try {
                    //console.log(data);
                    if (parseInt(data.code) < 0) {
                        //system error
                        alert('Internal error!');
                        return;
                    }
                    switch (action)
                    {
                        case 'login':
                            //console.log('data code: '+data.code);
                            if (data.code != 0) {
                                // show error
                                document.getElementById('LinkbookLoginError').innerHTML = data.message;
                            } else {
                                //console.log(data.login.json_order);
                                //repopulating plugin collection after login action;
                                //LinkbookPluginCollection.cleanup();//cleanup needed
                                //LinkbookPluginCollection.order = data.login.json_order;//repopulation
                                //LinkbookPluginCollection.run();
                                //console.log('new data'+data.login.product);
                                //this.showDiv('LinkbookParrentForm');
                                //console.log(data.login.product.product_name && data.login.product.product_name.length>0);
                                Linkbook.init_after_login(data.login.product.product_name && data.login.product.product_name.length > 0);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'logout':
                            hideAllDivs();
                            this.showDiv('LinkbookParrentLogin');
                            break;
                        case 'bookmarklet':
                            alert('Bookmarklet error');
                            break;
                        case 'follow':
                            if (data.code != 0)
                            {
                                document.getElementById('form_error_Linkbook').innerHTML = data.message;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                this.showDiv('LinkbookParrentSuccess');
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            alert('Unknown inBound action: ' + action);
                            break;
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    if (consoleLog) {
                        //console.log(err.toString());
                    }
                    alert('Something went wrong, server returned invalid message!');
                }
            }, //end f inBound()
            //method used to transfer the data from the bookmarklet to the server
            //outBound needs to know only the action, the parameters will be contructed, ex. : ?action=x&...
            outBound: function(action)
            {
                try {
                    switch (action)
                    {//start switch
                        case 'logout':
                            createElementScript(apiURL + '/MakeLogout');
                            break;
                        case 'login':
                            if (document.getElementById("form_remember").value == 'on')
                                form_remember_Linkbook = 1;
                            else
                                form_remember_Linkbook = 0;
                            createElementScript(apiURL + '/MakeLogin/email/' + document.getElementById("form_email").value + '/password/' + document.getElementById("form_password").value + '/remember/' + form_remember_Linkbook + '?url=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href));
                            break;
                        case 'follow':
                            if (true)
                            {
                                //document.getElementById('form_error_Linkbook').innerHTML = '';
                                var s = JSON.stringify({'url': location.href,
                                    'title': document.getElementById('linkbook_article_title').value,
                                    'description': document.getElementById('linkbook_article_textarea').value
                                });
                                if (s.length >= 2000) {
                                    alert('Payload length is over 2000, action may fail.');
                                }
                                createElementScript(apiURL + "/FollowProduct?input=" + encodeURIComponent(s));
                            } else {
                                // put error message on screen
                                document.getElementById('form_error_Linkbook').innerHTML = 'error';
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'report_broken_url':
                            this.showDiv('LinkbookParrentBroken');
                            //var s = JSON.stringify(LinkbookPluginCollection);
                            if (s.length >= 2000) {
                                alert('Payload length is over 2000, action may fail.');
                            }
                            createElementScript(apiURL + "/ReportBrokenUrl?input=" + encodeURIComponent(s));
                            break;
                        default:
                            alert('Unknown outBound action: ' + action);
                            break;
                    }//end switch
                }
                catch (err) {
                    if (consoleLog) {
                        //console.log(err.toString());
                    }
                    alert('Something went wrong, couldn\'t prepare data!');
                }


            }//end f outBound()
        }
        return f;
    }();
    var Linkbook = new LinkbookClass();
    Linkbook.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in my comments, there are two problems I see with your code *as-is*.

**First**, your closure is never executed - it's actually syntactically incorrect as-is. In your browser's console, it's the difference between this example:

```
function() { console.log('something'); }
```

And this one:

```
(function() { console.log('something'); })();
```

**Second**, `XMLHttpRequest` will only work within the context of the page's domain. (The script doesn't receive special privileges to the domain from which it comes.) So, given the nature of your script, it looks like `max-miller.local:3000` is *not* the intended domain-of-execution, and the request will fail.

Look into [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)-like solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup CORS permissions on your server?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

http://enable-cors.org/

If not, your AJAX will fail due to same-origin policy.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy